# Updating my fork from terminal without updating parent

Tags: linux, git, github, commit, git-fork

After going through other Q&As I couldn't quite find the answer I was looking for.

I've forked html5-boilerplate and have cloned it locally in Linux. I want to make changes locally then commit them to my fork *without* affecting or proposing changes to the original repository.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you commit changes to your fork, that's the only place the changes will go. It will not propose any changes to the original repository as long as you do not open a pull request or an owner of the repository pulls in your changes manually.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure and didn't want to inadvertently affect someone else's work. I appreciate you taking the time to comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've forked html5-boilerplate and have cloned it locally in Linux.

If you will push your changes (using `git push`), they will be pushed in your fork if you cloned the forked repository.

If you cloned the source repository and want to push the changes in the fork, you have to add a new remote or pass the fork url in the `git push` command:

```
git remote add myFork https://github.com/owner/forked-repo.git
git push myFork --all
```

or:

```
git push https://github.com/owner/forked-repo.git --all
```